# How can I define manual MAC with vmware_guest in Ansible for vyOS VM?

Tags: ansible, vmware

I need to define static MAC bindings in the network section for vyOS VM. I use this Playbook, which works for Cento's or other VM's, but not for vyOS:

```
- name: "Deploy vyOS VM"
  hosts: vyos
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Deploy vyOS VM from template
      ignore_errors: yes
      community.vmware.vmware_guest:
        hostname: '{{ vsphere_host }}'
        username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
        password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
        validate_certs: false
        datacenter: 'OVH'
        state: present
        folder: '/OVH/vm'
        name: Test
        networks: 
          - name: Management
            mac: "00:50:56:8d:d0:01"
          - name: Management
            mac: "00:50:56:8d:d0:02"
          - name: Management
            mac: "00:50:56:8d:d0:03"
          - name: Management
            mac: "00:50:56:8d:d0:04"
        template: vyOS_Template
        wait_for_ip_address: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: vm
```

I always got this error:

```
TASK [Deploy vyOS VM from template] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [1-INET-backbone-vyOS]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: 'Failed to create a virtual machine : Customization of the guest operating system ''debian6_64Guest'' is not supported in this configuration. Microsoft Vista (TM) and Linux guests with Logical Volume Manager are supported only for recent ESX host and VMware Tools versions. Refer to vCenter documentation for supported configurations.'
...ignoring
```

When I change the type to Centos4/5 64bit, I can assign the MAC but the Network Cards are not connected.

Question:
Can somebody show me an example, how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I moved to a newer vyOS version and now it works again